# How to change json to camelCase in .NET Core 3.1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After upgrading to 3.1.1 , AddNewsoftJson is missing, how to change the json casing format now?

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is moved to a nuget package.

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 3.1.1`

Install this package and include the following namespace in the startup class - `ConfigureServices` method.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
new DefaultContractResolver()
```

instead of

```
new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

worked for me

Comment: The original question asked how to change it to "CamelCase" which isn't actually in camel casing (it's Pascal casing). I've edited the question title to read "cameCase". If you're after PascalCase then yes you would use `DefaultContractResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this third-party blog](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/), it appears to be a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) now, so you'll have to install it in your project:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.1.1

Your code should then work.